# How to get user info from WebContext?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

My SL app use windowes authentication.

When app started, Following code add user info to colloection:

```
 public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create a WebContext and add it to the ApplicationLifetimeObjects
        // collection.  This will then be available as WebContext.Current.

        WebContext webContext = new WebContext();
        webContext.Authentication = new WindowsAuthentication() { DomainContext = new AMSRIAServices.Web.AuthenticationContext() };
        this.ApplicationLifetimeObjects.Add(webContext);
    }
```

Then in any code-behind of user control, I want to get back the user info. I tried to use WebContext.Current.User, but I get nothing. How to get user info from Application.Current.ApplicationLifetimeObjects in code?

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern would be to include a static property of called `Current` on your context type then assign that during the `StartService` method.

```
public class MyWebContext : IAppicationService
{

   public MyWebContext Current {get; private set}


   public void StartService(ApplicationServiceContext context)
   {
      Current = this;
      // Other initialisation code
   }
   // Rest of implementation

}
```

Hence accessing your webContext object is simply:-

```
MyWebContext.Current.DoStuff();
```

Comment: Thanks. I already have WebContext and set it in app starting point(see post, I add the app()). It is available for SL app. I want to know how to get it.

Comment: @KentZhou: in that case it will already have derived from WebContextBase and have a `Current` property.  I don't really know enough about WCF RIA Services to know why the User isn't configured yet, it could be an asynchronous thing or that Login needs to happen first.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Application_Startup you need to do a LoadUser:

WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoadUser();

although I am having a similar problem getting the user to load. But I am using formsauthentication. If you create a Silverlight Business Application and check out the app.xaml.cs you can see an example of how to do this.

Let me know if it works for you with windows auth.